# Is it possible to solve for values in a matrix such that all rows and columns have equal sum?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, multivalued-functions

Is it possible to solve for values in a grid such that all rows have the same sum and all columns have the same sum where values in the table can be any real number?

meaning:

```
A B C D = x
E F G H = x
I J K L = x
M N O P = x
= = = =
y y y y

A+B+C+D=x  A+D+G+K=y
E+F+G+H=x  B+F+J+N=Y
```

I have developed a brute force genetic solver to find very near to correct values but I have to believe there is a better solution out there.

Many Thanks

Comment: Is $A+D+G+K=y$?

Comment: Did you mean to write $A + E + I + M = y$?

Comment: Yes sorry, my apologies

Comment: Note that in the example you must have $x=y$; similarly for any square matrix example.

Answer (score 2):

A *permutation matrix* is a 0, 1 square matrix with a single 1 in each row and in each column. Clearly, all the row sums and all the column sums of a permutation matrix are 1. Now if $P_1,P_2,\dots,P_r$ are permutation matrices, and $c_1,c_2,\dots,c_r$ are any real numbers, then $$c_1P_1+c_2P_2+\cdots+c_rP_r$$ has the property that every row sum and every column sum is $c_1+c_2+\cdots+c_r$. So this lets you construct as many of these matrices as you'd like.

What's more, it can be proved that every square matrix with all row sums and all column sums equal can be written as such a linear combination of permutation matrices, so this construction doesn't just get lots of matrices, it gets all of them.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this problem will only exist when $x = y$.

To see this, note that the sum of all entries in the matrix must be equal to both $4x$ and to $4y$, hence $4x = 4y$, hence $x = y$.

Comment: The particular case where $x=y=1$ are called stochastic matrices, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix for properties that could be of interest.

Comment: @kuifje excellent name! I know him as Tintin. Also, the question allows negative entries, so you're not quite correct there.

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom  thanks for the correction. And I'm glad the name Kuifje has appealed to you!!

Comment: $x=y=1$ and all entries between zero and one, those are called *doubly* stochastic.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I was entirely clear, but here is one of the results that I was able to acheive from the brute force evolutionary solver I developed.

```
A B C D E        .6570  .7448   .7009   .7448   .6570  =  3.5045
F G H I J        .7448  .6570   .7009   .6570   .7448  =  3.5045
K L M N O        .7009  .7009   .7009   .7009   .7009  =  3.5045
P Q R S T        .7009  .7009   .7009   .7009   .7009  =  3.5045
U V W X Y        .7448  .6570   .7009   .6570   .7448  =  3.5045
Z @ $ % ^        .6570  .7448   .7009   .7448   .6570  =  3.5045
                   =       =       =       =       =
                 4.2054  4.2054  4.2054  4.2054  4.2054

Where values of inputs are fixed as A=E=Z=^
                                    B=D=F=J=U=Y=@=% etc,
```

While similar results are acheived with all unique possible inputs things are simplified to speed up the solver.

I am just wondering if there is any other way to achieve the same results in a more elegant fashion. I am noticing some interesting patterns emerging so I have to guess there might be a set of equations to solve for inputs given desired outputs. However, I am only an architect with some math coding and math experience, no specific expertise in these realms.

Best

Comment: Setting all entries equal to $\cfrac{3.5045}5 = \cfrac{4.2054}6 = 0.7009$ also works.